# Change Vim configurable based on filetype

Tags: vim

Is there a way where I can set vim to configure itself based on the filetype?  So for example,  text files have the equivalent of

:set spell
:syntax off

Where a C source file has

:syntax on
:smartindent on

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

VIM 'ftplugins' are there exactly for this purpose.

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_43.html#filetype-plugin

Answer (score 0):

I like my python files correct, so my .vimrc has:

```
augroup filetypedetect
        au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py set ts=4 sw=4 et ai
augroup END
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use :setl[ocal] instead of :set for things like ts, sw, et and ai.

However some things are global and can not be set per buffer and :syntax is one of them.
You may try this to turn syntax off for current file:

```
:setl ft=
```

And as Jacek has pointed out ftplugins are the way.